# Total free memory java

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I'm wondering why total free memory doesn't change after creating big table. But when I use garbage collector total free memory increases.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
    C c = new C();

    System.out.println("Free memory: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    c.CreateTable();
    System.out.println("Free memory: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Free memory: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
 }
}


class C{
 public void createTable()
 {
    int[] ar = new int[70000];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i<ar.length;i++)
    {
        ar[i]=r.nextInt(99);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Here's some nice article about [Garbage Collector](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/). Might give you a little bit of the idea of how the GC works.

Comment: 70k `int`s insn't exactly what I would call a "big table" in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JVM created int[] ar in TLAB (thread-local allocation buffer).Let me explain this with the following example:

1) Suppose total memory in the system was 100 units.

2) The current thread has already created a TLAB beofre even a single line of code has run.

3) TLAB's memory(say 10 units) is already deducted from the total memory i.e (Runtime.freeMemory shows 90 units)

4) int[] ar is created inside TLAB as TLAB has free space.

5) After creating of int[] ar running Runtime.freeMemory showed 90 units ( as it is created inside the TLAB).

6) Now on doing GC you get to see 100 units again

Comment: do you mean when gc is called at the end, TLAB is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the behavior you claim is occurring:

```
$ java Main 
Free memory: 126206592
Free memory: 125535432
Free memory: 125943720
```

As you can see, the free memory reduces after calling `createTable()` and then increases again after calling `System.gc()`.

Now you don't get all of the allocated memory back<sup>1</sup>, but there are lots of possible explanations for that including:

- extra classes may have been loaded resulting in increased heap usage
- some code may have been JIT compiled resulting in increased heap usage
- objects may have been allocated in a region of the heap that is collected infrequently.  For example, a large array may be allocated directly into tenured space ...

Summary:  Java memory allocation / garbage collection is complicated ... and beginners are better off<sup>2</sup> not trying to figure out how it works using simple (naive) "black box" tests.  You will learn more by finding / reading articles.

---

<sup>1 - To be precise, the GC *may be* reclaiming all of the memory that the call explicitly allocated ... but there are other things going on that mean that this is not reflected in the "free space" figure.</sup>

<sup>2 - If your head explodes, it will leave nasty stains on the carpet ..... :-)</sup>